# Error with android resource linking failed

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

[I cant fix this error for 2 days, please help!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTOxU.png)

I run into issue while creating xml files and stuck over the days. I cant understand what the issue can be checked my xml files over and over again but there is no highlights drawn by android studio and everything looks fine. However after writing a couple of classes my builder failed to execute the code returning this error. Please help!!!!

Comment: Can you add some code that might relate to that particular issue.

Comment: Me myself running into such error for the first time and no idea how that got in my code

Answer (score 0):

Most likely xml grammar errors. For example, if you write `android:onClick` as `android:onclick` when you create an Android button component, you might get that error. Look carefully at the values.xml file.

Comment: I do not have values.xml in my values folder, there are only styles, colors and strings. I have checked my xml files everything is fine but still not working